# Can we capture the same browser closing event without using "onunload"

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Actually using the `window.close`, we can control whether browser is closed or not, but it works only for pop-ups created by the browser.

So, are there any ways to listen to the closing event of the browser without using `onunload`? Because we don't want things to be executed when *back*, *refresh* or *forward* actions occur.

Please also reply if you know specifics regarding Firefox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seriously, doing this on your website is **very rude**. If people want to go, let them.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to manipulate the EXPECTED behaviour of the browser, essentially taking away people's ability to navigate. Fortunately browser developers were smart enough to disallow this - so the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to catch the browser/tab close in some manner different than onunload, because i want to perform some validation in that case but not in all onunload possibilities that exist in my page and this is a valid use case for me.